# Taking a screenshot of everything but 1 window

Tags: python, pyqt5, pywin32, win32gui

Ok, so I want to continuously screenshot the main screen (at something like 30 images per second), but I want my PyQt5 app to be invisible on the screenshot image. The app should stay on the screen at the same time (I am drawing things on the app based on the screenshot of the image)

Is there a way for my PyQt5 app to be invisible to my screenshots ?

Here is the function I currently use to take a screenshot :

```
def screenshot_screen(self, coords=None):
    hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    if coords != None:
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = coords
    else:
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    width = x1 - x0
    height = y1 - y0

    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dcObj=win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC=dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, width, height)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)

    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), dcObj, (x0+1, y0+1), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    im = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.frombuffer(im, dtype='uint8')

    img.shape = (height, width, 4)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

    return img
```

To be clear, the yellow rects are from my pyqt5 app, I would want them drawing like they are on the right, but I wouldn't want them on the left window that shows the screenshot that is being taken:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you hide the window before taking the screenshot and show it afterwards?

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried it with win32gui.ShowWindow(app_hwnd, False) but I take 30 screenshots per seconds so it makes my app flicker and act weird. I edited my question to make it more clear. Thanks